# Why updating meta from front-end needs i get old value?

Tags: php, wordpress

The new value is sent to the db and the page refreshes on submit, but the field
becomes empty. If I then manually refresh the page again, then I see
the new value. Any idea why?

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="myForm" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="dateChange" type="text" name="input-test" value="<?php echo str_replace('_', '', $jikuDate); ?>"  autocomplete="off">
    <input id="test-form" type="submit" name="updateDate" value="Update">
</form>
```

and then I do

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['updateDate'])){
       $post = array(
          'ID' => $id
       );
       if ('Update' === ($_POST['updateDate'] ?? false)) {
         update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'usp-custom-14', $_POST['input-test']);
       }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Have an array `$post = array` and use it as object `$post->ID` could be the problem after a quick look. Also a `}` is missing?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden updated with the missing } Thanks. What do you mean with $post array? Code example pls?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden you mean doing `update_post_meta( $post, 'usp-custom-14', $_POST['input-test']);` ?

Comment: Your `$post` var is an array, so I guess you should use it as `$post['ID']` instead of `$post->ID`.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden nope, same thing, i update the field, page refreshes, it gets empty, then i manually refresh and I see the new value

Comment: It is fixing your code, not your problem ;) On-topic: is the PHP code before or after the HTML called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171625/discussion-between-rob-m-and-ron-van-der-heijden).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved it, not the most elegant probably:

First:

```
<?php
    $jikuDate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'usp-custom-14', true);
    if (isset($_POST['updateDate'])) {
        // Execute this code if the submit button is pressed.
        $jikuDate = $_POST['input-test'];
    }
?>
```

Then the html:

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="myForm" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="dateChange" type="text" name="input-test" value="<?php echo str_replace('_', '', $jikuDate); ?>"  autocomplete="off">
    <input id="test-form" type="submit" name="updateDate" value="Update">
</form>
```

Then:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {
        if ('Update' === ($_POST['updateDate'] ?? false)) {
            $post = array(
                'ID' => $id
            );
            $jikuDate = $_POST['input-test'];
            update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'usp-custom-14', $_POST['input-test']);
        }
    }
?>
```